# Lift of a bivector

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, tangent-bundle

Let $\pi : M \to B$ be a fiber bundle, and suppose that $X$ is a vector field on $B$. A lift of $X$ is a vector field, $\widehat{X}$, on $M$ which maps to $X$ under the differential $d\pi: TM \to TB$. This choice is not unique, and any other such choice of lift differs from $\widehat{X}$ by a vector tangent to the fiber of the projection $\pi:M \to B$. A connection for the bundle determines a choice of such a lift, by splitting the sequence
\begin{align*}
0 \longrightarrow VM \longrightarrow TM \longrightarrow \pi^{\ast}TB \longrightarrow 0
\end{align*}
Suppose now that I have a bivector $\alpha \in \Lambda^2 TB$.

### Questions

1. Does a choice of connection for $\pi:M \to B$ also determine a lift of $\alpha$ to $\Lambda^2 TM$?
2. If yes to 1., suppose that under a choice of connection $\widehat{X} = X+x$ and $\widehat{Y} = Y+y$ are the lifts of two vector fields $X$ and $Y$. Is the lift of $X\wedge Y$ given by $$\widehat{X \wedge Y} = \widehat{X} \wedge \widehat{Y} = X\wedge Y + X \wedge y + x \wedge Y + x \wedge y $$
3. How are the answers to 1. and 2. related to the above sequence?
4. Does this naturally extend to higher exterior powers?

Comment: If $\widehat{X}$ is a lift of $X$ then $X$ and $\widehat{X}$ are vector fields on two distinct manifolds. Hence, the equality $\widehat{X}=X+x$ makes no sense.

Comment: The notation is a bit sloppy. If I were being pedantic I could have written it as $\widehat{X} = a(X) + y$, where $y \in \Gamma(VM)$, $X \in \Gamma(\pi^{\ast}TB)$ and $a: \Gamma(\pi^{\ast}TB) \to \Gamma(TM)$ is the connection defining the choice of splitting.

Comment: What you explain in your comment means that $x=0$.